# Convert Python re.sub to C#

Tags: c#, python, regex

I'm trying to do a conversion from Python to C#

```
   sconvert = re.sub(r"([.$+?{}()\[\]\\])", r"\\\1", sconvert)
```

I couldn't find a C#.Net equivalent to this function to make it easy.

From the Python Manual

> re.sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0) Return the string obtained by replacing the leftmost non-overlapping occurrences of
>   pattern in string by the replacement repl. If the pattern isn’t found,
>   string is returned unchanged. repl can be a string or a function; if
>   it is a string, any backslash escapes in it are processed. That is, \n
>   is converted to a single newline character, \r is converted to a
>   carriage return, and so forth. Unknown escapes such as \j are left
>   alone. Backreferences, such as \6, are replaced with the substring
>   matched by group 6 in the pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for a [`Regex.Escape` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Escapes a minimal set of characters (`\`, `*`, `+`, `?`, `|`, `{`, `[`, `(`,`)`, `^`, `$`,`.`, `#`, and *white space*) by replacing them with their escape codes. This instructs the regular expression engine to interpret these characters literally rather than as metacharacters.

The `sconvert = re.sub(r"([.$+?{}()\[\]\\])", r"\\\1", sconvert)` code escapes the characters specified in the `[.$+?{}()\[\]\\]` range to match literal characters they denote.

Note that `Regex.Escape` also escapes spaces. If you do not want that, use your custom replace:

```
var input = "|^.$+?{}()[]\\-";
var escaped = Regex.Replace(input, @"[|^.$+?{}()\[\]\\-]", "\\$&");
Console.Write(escaped);
// => \|\^\.\$\+\?\{\}\(\)\[\]\\\-
```

I suggest adding `|`, `-` and `^`, too. See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/ywLnTj)

Comment: The escape function escapes more characters then I want to escape.

Comment: Yes, so, use your own replacement code. I suggest adding `|`, `-` and `^`, too. Note that in .NET regex you do not have to ever escape `{`, `}`, `#` and spaces (unless the hashes and spaces are used in a regex that is compiled with `RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace` modifier).

Comment: Thanks, regex is just so foreign to me.

Comment: The replacement might be a bit tricky: `\\$&` replaces with a literal ``\`` and the whole matched text as `$&` is  a backreference to the whole match (not just captured submatches). It is a kind of  a shortcut so as not to add extra groups as in your pattern. In Python, you can use `\g<0>`. See [`print(re.sub(r"[.$+?{}()\[\]\\]", r"\\\g<0>", '[.$+?{}()[]\\]'))`](http://ideone.com/WYRaKw). [*The backreference `\g<0>` substitutes in the entire substring matched by the RE.*](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)

Comment: Following your example, in Python `escaped.replace("^", "(?:[^\w\d_\-.%]|$)")` Would that translate to C# - like this `escaped = regex.replace(escaped,"^","(?:[^\w\d_\-.%]|$)")` ?

Comment: Technically yes, just 1 note: `\w` matches all Unicode letters and digits in .NET. In Python, if you do not use `re.U`, `\w` matches only ASCII letters and digits. `\d` is redundant in these patterns, remove it. I do not know what you want to do with the pattern. Use regex101.com to check what the pattern means.

Comment: Based on regex101.com - it looks like the `_` is also redundant also, because `\w` would encapsulate that also, or am i interpreting it incorrectly?

Comment: Yes, a purist would use `Regex.Replace("Mystring", @"(?:[^\w.%-]|$)", "REPLACEMENT_PATTERN");`. I do not understand why you need an alternative with the end of string anchor `|$`, but I hope you know what you are doing.